# Is there a way to have cross-project fixVersions in Jira?

Tags: jira

We have several, independent teams that have their own priorities and work. Yet the teams are all on the same code-base, so when we deploy, everyone's code goes out at the same time.

How have you dealt with this using Jira?

A couple of possibilities come to mind:

- if there were cross-project fixVersions, that would be ideal, as each release would be synchronized
- we could use tags and update all the filters everyone uses to segment what people see
- we could manually keep the fixVersions in sync, ug
- we could use their API to manage fixVersions, to keep them in sync
- something else entirely

Answer (score 2):

There is an existing JIRA for this at https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-2698 which you can vote for and wait patiently til the end of time.

There are a couple ghetto ways you could do this without coding:

- Have them share the same project, but use the Component dropdown to separate the work.
- Using the new Greenhopper at least you can have a cross-project sprint and then you'd just have to have a manually sync'ed up version across projects.

Answer (score 2):

For those interested: we have just launched our Version Sync add-on for JIRA to the Marketplace that will do exactly this. It will automatically keep versions in sync between multiple projects, where you have one "Master" project and an unlimited number of linked projects to which version changes are propagated.

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/net.collabsoft.plugins.jira.jira-version-sync

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is an out of the box solution for this problem, but you can automate version creation across projects via [Jira Command Line Tool](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JCLI/JIRA+Command+Line+Interface).